# How to replace a part of a string of a .txt file with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn php by making a simple text editor like thing.
So I made a class that should replace a string of a text file, but seems like it's not working. I would be glad if you can help me out. Here's the part of the code.

```
  <?php
    $classer = new editorCore();
    $classer->transaction($_POST['oldString'],$_POST['newString']);

    class editorCore{

        public $oldString;
        public $newString;

        function transaction($oldString,$newString){

          if(isset($oldString)&&isset($newString)){

              $this->oldString = $oldString;
              $this->newString =$newString;
            $classer = new editorCore();    
            $say =$classer->caller();
            echo $say;

            }else{
                echo "There is an error";
            }
        }

         function  caller(){

            $line = file('test.txt');
            foreach($line as $li){
               $rep = str_replace($this->oldString,  $this->newString, $li);

            }
        //wanted to replace the  string and display it to the html 

              $line = file('test.txt');
            foreach($line as $li){
                   echo $li;
            }

        echo "<br />";
       }       
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: "seems like it's not working" , well that narrows it down

Comment: Get specific.  What's the problem? What did you input? What did you expect to output? What *was* output?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.Well, the problem is that I've made a simple code that you can enter  two sets of strings, one for searching the string and another for replacement. And send the input data via ajax to the class. The class called "editorCore" above contains the functions that will replace the strings in the text file but doesn't work.

Comment: There are a few things wrong. Your `transaction()` method creates a new instance of editorCore. Why? You should just call `echo $this->caller();`.  Inside `caller()` you set `$rep` but you don't use it.  You load the file again and echo it out, but you should be returning data instead of echoing since `transaction()` will echo.